# GitHub README.md files are displaying '#' symbols instead of rendering as <headers>

Tags: github, hash, header, markdown

github readme.md files are displaying '#' symbols instead of rendering as headers

```
#Please FORK this project

##Visit our descriptive wiki
```

instead of being rendered as:

## Please FORK this project

### Visit our descriptive wiki

from what i can tell, it just started out of nowhere, it used to be fine - dumb, i know.

any advice?

Comment: I had this problem earlier today and ended up just copying/pasting code from a working md file.  That will solve your problem in the short term, but I'd love to see a real answer to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have a space after the `#` character before the text.  That will give you what you want.

### Then you will get what you want!

In general, Markdown is pretty picky about spaces, horizontal and vertical, so try adding whitespace when things don't render the way you want.