# Header in Rmarkdown is not displaying in a required format

Tags: r, r-markdown

[image]

In the html report, It is looking like this

[image]

What could be the problem here?...Header is not displaying in a required format

Comment: Have you tried... putting a space there? As in "## Exploratory Data Analysis"

Comment: You're missing a space after `##`.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as output here? Also you should share your code as text rather than a picture so we can copy/paste to test it.

Comment: Please never post screenshots of code, always include them as text so that users trying to help you, don't have to retype the whole thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42824414/5325862